# Can you initialize an abstract class so you can set it equal to a child class later?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
abstract class BaseAnimal;
class cat : BaseAnimal;
class dog : BaseAnimal;


var allAnimals = new list<BaseAnimal>();

foreach (var someVar in allVars)
{
    var myAnimal = new BaseAnimal();

    if (someVar == true)
    {
        myAnimal = new cat();
    }
    else
    {
        myAnimal = new dog();
    }


    /* do other things with myAnimal var */
    allAnimals.add(myAnimal);
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this, or am I going to have to initialize the variable in each IF statement and then duplicate the other stuff/put it in a function and call it twice?

Comment: Please note that C# is case-sensitive. It's worth putting effort into making your sample code as realistic as possible - which means using `List` instead of `list`, `Add` instead of `add`, and giving your classes names which follow normal conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't initialize it in this case (or you would initialize it to null), but yes, what you ask is possible.

```
BaseAnimal myAnimal;

if (someVar) {
    var myCat = new cat();

    // Do things with myCat that are cat-specific.

    myAnimal = myCat;
} else {
    var myDog = new dog();

    // Do things with myDog that are dog-specific.

    myAnimal = myDog;
}

allAnimals.add(myAnimal);
```

Comment: I have some properties that are on cat that are not on dog and vice versa. When I try the above strategy, and then try to access the property on cat or dog, I get: BaseAnimal does not contain a definition for .....  Do I just need to add these properties to baseAnimal?

Comment: If you need to do that, then do it inside of the `if` block.  I will update my answer to show this in code.

Comment: @user1652427: Well where do you need to access the property? It looks like you basically haven't given us all your requirements, which makes it very hard to give you a satisfactory answer...

Comment: I am doing this within the IF statement, but it's not working. @JonSkeet, I was trying to avoid writing out all the code as I originally didn't think it necessary.

Comment: @user1652427 If you are doing it within the `if` block then my updated code sample should work for you.

Comment: @user1652427: Well you need to include at least something which is *representative* of the code you need. Are you just setting properties on the animal? If so, an object initializer is probably the simplest approach.

Comment: An object initializer would definitely be preferable, yes... it would avoid retaining a second variable for the more-specific type.  Of course, since the OP wasn't clear, I've made my code as generic as possible.  But coders should prefer whatever form turns out to be the most readable.

Answer (score 6):

Just declare the variable without assigning it a value:

```
BaseAnimal myAnimal;
```

Why would you *want* to assign a value to it, knowing that the value would be overwritten immediately anyway?

Note that in your case, the variable will be *definitely assigned* after the `if/else` statement anyway, so that's not an issue - you'll still be able to read the variable value when adding the item to the list.

Of course, you could also consider using the conditional operator:

```
var myAnimal = someVar ? (BaseAnimal) new Cat() : new Dog();
```

Here the cast to `BaseAnimal` is only required because of the way the conditional operator works - the overall type of the expression has to be *either* the type of the second argument *or* the type of the third argument.

EDIT: If you need to set animal-specific properties, it's simplest to use an object initializer in the `if` statement:

```
if (someVar)
{
    myAnimal = new Cat { Lives = 9 };
}
else
{
    myAnimal = new Dog { Shaggy = true };
}
```

If you need to call methods on it, you'll need a separate local variable of the specific type:

```
if (someVar)
{
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    cat.Groom();
    myAnimal = cat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot

```
 var myAnimal = new BaseAnimal();
```

The compiler won't let you do this. What you can do, though, is cast a more derived class to a less derived class, like in

```
BaseAnimal ba = myDog;
```

You can have your list the way you want, and can add other animals like `Cat`s and `Dog`s like

```
allAnimals.Add(myDog);
```

Comment: I mixed it up... Thank you for clarification